# python - edit a text file

Tags: python, text, text-files

I am using python and i want to delete some characters from the end of a text file.
The file is big a and i dont want to read all of it and duplicate the interesting part.
My best guess is that i need to change the file size....

can anyone help me please
thanks

Comment: Can you provide the last line of the file? Is what you want to remove a string of fixed length?

Comment: No.I do not know the size of the section. I jump to specific place in the file and checks the value,  If the value does not match what I want, I want to delete the file from that point

Comment: Well, obviously if your "specific place" was specified with a line number or string, you'd need to use a brute-force search, so I assume you have a byte offset to work with?  As dmitko says, you and seek there, read enough data to do your verifation.  File objects have a truncate(new-size) method you can use if necessary.

Comment: Thank. I will use the truncate function.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you need to open the file, seek to the end, delete characters and save it.

seek ( http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek ) accepts negative values (e.g. `f.seek(-3, os.SEEK_END)` sets the position to the third to last), so that you can easily go to the end of your file.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects - this link may be a good starting point.