# edit interfaces file under /etc/network in Raspberry-Pi using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm currently working with RaspberryPi-3 with Rasbian installed. I want to auto-reconnect to a network to a specific network. Going through the internet, I found out a way to do it i.e. by editing the interfaces file under /etc/network. I want to edit this file using some script (preferably Python-3). I just need to add these lines to the interfaces file:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid <my-SSID>
    wpa-psk <my-PassKey>
```

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: You may find existing answers that will help by searching for things like "python edit file" or "python append lines to file".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - edit a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657109/python-edit-a-text-file)

Comment: Whatever you see on configure wi-fi setting on `/etc/network` is outdated since Debian/Raspian Jessie. The setting should be done via `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: Furthermore, auto reconnect of wifi can be done via linux system [configuration](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5341/58715) than using python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no specific reason to do that in Python I'd suggest a simple shell script like:

```
MYSSID=WiFi1
WIFIPW=Zekrett1

cat >> /etc/network/interfaces << EoNet
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid $MYSSID
    wpa-psk  $WIFIPW
EoNet
```

the same in Python 2/3:

```py
ssid='WiFi1'
wifipw='Zekrett1'

with open('/etc/network/interfaces', 'a') as netcfg:
    netcfg.write('auto wlan0\n'
                 'iface wlan0 inet dhcp\n'
                 '    wpa-ssid {}\n'
                 '    wpa-psk  {}\n'.format(ssid, wifipw))
```

Comment: There is a small correction though! The path should be /etc/network/interfaces instead of /etc/network