# Python: Using write() function to output three variables

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to make the program write these in a new file. It is easy to do each line by itself, but combined is making problems.

```
line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."


#this here results a syntax error..
target.write (\%r, \%r, \%r) % (line1, line2, line3)

#what do?
```

Comment: You can just write one string at a time, so you have to create one string containing all three strings (using `format`, string concatenation, ...).

Comment: do not use % in 2019 and stick any number of variables like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313512/228117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
targe.write('{} {} {}'.format(line1,line2,line3))
```

or old format way:

```
target.write('%r %r %r' % (line1,line2,line3))
```

Answer (score 1):

With python 3 you can use f strings

```
target.write (f"{line1} {line2} {line3}")
```

You can find much more about f-strings here on offical docs
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can concatenate strings using `+` operator, so try:

```
target.write(line1+line2+line3)
```

EDIT: Version with newlines:

```
target.write(line1+"\n"+line2+"\n"+line3)
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked! although when I tried to add a line break between them it erred.

Answer (score 0):

Using your current method of writing the lines, you need to have the "%r"s in a string, and the "% (line1, line2, line3)" needs to be in the "target.write()" function call

```
target.write("%r %r %r" % (line1, line2, line3)
```

But you cold also try using the writelines method

```
with open("test.txt", "w+") as file:
    file.writelines([line1, line2, line3])
```

You can also wrap your inputs into a loop to get an arbitrary amount of lines from the user

```
lines = []
lineCount = 5

for l in range(lineCount):
    lines.append(input("Line %d: " % l) + "\n")

with open("test.txt", "w+") as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```